# How to get specific Attributes of Object in GET request (with REST client)?

Tags: rest

Guys i have a backend with a method that returns a finalList, which I wanted to test in my plugin "Advanced REST client", that can call different Methods combined with a request URL.

The method:

```
@GetMapping("/vokabelListe")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Vokabel[] getVokabelListe() {

        for (int i = 0; i < sehrWahrscheinlich.length; i++) {
            if (finalList.length < 10) {
                finalList[i].setVokabelENG(sehrWahrscheinlich[i].getVokabelENG());
                finalList[i].setVokabelDE(sehrWahrscheinlich[i].getVokabelDE());
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < wahrscheinlich.length; i++) {
            if (finalList.length < 13) {
                finalList[i].setVokabelENG(sehrWahrscheinlich[i].getVokabelENG());
                finalList[i].setVokabelDE(sehrWahrscheinlich[i].getVokabelDE());
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nichtWahrscheinlich.length; i++) {
            if (finalList.length < 15) {
                finalList[i].setVokabelENG(sehrWahrscheinlich[i].getVokabelENG());
                finalList[i].setVokabelDE(sehrWahrscheinlich[i].getVokabelDE());
            }
        }

        while (finalList.length < 15) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sehrWahrscheinlich.length; i++) {
                finalList[i].setVokabelENG(sehrWahrscheinlich[i].getVokabelENG());
                finalList[i].setVokabelDE(sehrWahrscheinlich[i].getVokabelDE());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < wahrscheinlich.length; i++) {
                finalList[i].setVokabelENG(sehrWahrscheinlich[i].getVokabelENG());
                finalList[i].setVokabelDE(sehrWahrscheinlich[i].getVokabelDE());
                }
            for (int i = 0; i < nichtWahrscheinlich.length; i++) {
                finalList[i].setVokabelENG(sehrWahrscheinlich[i].getVokabelENG());
                finalList[i].setVokabelDE(sehrWahrscheinlich[i].getVokabelDE());
                }
        }

        return finalList;
    }
```

I just tested it, but it returns null for all indexes. I have to go through all indexes and get each VokabelDE, but i dont know how..

Comment: How should this code compile, there's not even a definition of `finalList`

Comment: Its obove the method:


    Vokabel[] finalList = new Vokabel[15];

Comment: So, if `finalList` is defined as length 15 how should any one of the if statements be `true`?

Comment: Oh LOL ur right, but i want to have an array which will be filled during the method. So how do i fill an array that has actually no slots?

Comment: Use an index (as local variable) to track the current position of the array for example.